# MSVC Output filename of file being compiled

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, precompiled-headers

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.  When I *Build Solution* I sometimes get an error like this:

```
C2825 'TContainer' must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'    MyProject   MyHeaderFile.h
```

As `MyHeaderFile.h` is a template file I want to know which file is including it as that is where the error is.
How can I get the build to show me something like:

```
Compiling 'MySourceFile.cpp'
C2825 'TContainer' must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'    MyProject   MyHeaderFile.h
```

I've tried every compiler switch.
I'm currently have to compile each .cpp that includes that header individually to find the problem.
I am using precompiled headers.
Edit:
I've noticed that #pragma message("MySourceFile.cpp") does not output the filename either.  I don't know if this is a clue.

Edit, for those that asked, here is the proof that the cpp filename is not included in the Output windows.
[image: Build Output Window]

Edit:
Normal Console Wizard build for Vlad:
[image]

Comment: Please make sure to add the C++ tag to C++ questions. For this question, the `verbosity` tag seems pointless, though several other tags seem unnecessary as well.

Comment: Please quote the complete error messages from the Output window literally, including the surrounding ones. They should point to the exact source files and line numbers.

Comment: @dvix I have the exact line point in the _header_ file that the error is occuring but it is due to the use of the template.  If I use the same template with a different .cpp it works.  It's not the location of the error I'm looking for, it is the origin of it.  If I had the name of the file being compiled that would narrow it down sufficiently.

Comment: @Ant Errors in the Output window show the originating source file and line number. Make sure you are looking at the Output window, the one opened from the menu View / Output.

Comment: @dxiv Aah! I know. It's not the source file and line number that I want to see.  It's the file which is including that file because that is where the error is.  It does **not** show me the name of the .cpp file.  It **does** show me the name of the header file (and the line number) on which the error occurs.

Comment: @Ant The output window *does* show where the error originates. Feel free to prove me wrong by posting the code snippet and a screenshot or copy/paste of the *entire* output window.

Comment: @dxiv If I go to the effort of recreating the error and posting the output pane and it shows no source filename, will you have a helpful suggestion?

Comment: @Ant Providing context and details improves your chances at getting better answers. Whether that's worth the effort is yours to weigh.

Comment: See edit to original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build And Run:

`"MSBuild project build output verbosity:"` - whe I set it to `Quiet` - the file names are gone, together with `#pragma message`

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  That was it.  I've set it to Minimal and now see both the filename of the file being compiled and the pragma messages.  Sorry again I sounded ungrateful before.  Do you think it's worth editing your answer to show only the latter part?

Comment: @Ant - Great! Done. I've also deleted "debugging" messages; you can do too